# onunload event fires before window.close

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add Spotify Login pop-up to my website. Everything is ready but window.unonload runs before i close window.

This is really going to drive me crazy. I'm trying to find solution for 2 hours in web but couldn't.

Look at this image. Window is still open but unload event fired [image]

```
/**
 * @description Spotify Login. Creates New Window.
 */
export const authorize = async () => {

    let url = await axios.get(apiUrl("/api/authorize"));

    var loginWindow = window.open(url.data, "Spotify Login", "width=600,height=800");

    loginWindow.onunload = () => {
        console.log("Fetching Token load");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Your logic explicitly is defining an `onunload` method.

Comment: When i open new window this event fires immediately. It doesn't event wait for window.close. 
Look at console, but window is still open. https://i.imgur.com/VMqu86k.png

Comment: im guessing the page redirects which would cause an onunload

Comment: unclear how you would bind an event to a window in another domain.

Comment: Feel free to add your solution as an answer to the post instead of updating your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In new window when i get token i save it to localstorage and close the window. In main window i watch for changes in localstorage then do my stuff and remove the event.

```
export const authorize = async () => {
    let url = await axios.get(apiUrl("/api/authorize"));
    window.open(url.data);
    const handleStorage = () => {
        store.commit('setLogged', true);
        store.commit('setStatus');
        window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorage)
    }
    window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorage);
}
```